Plotting spatial data in Python
I am very new to mapping in Python and I'm trying to plot data through Jupyter Notebook -
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import geopandas as gpd

DS = xr.open_dataset("/path/to/file/data.nc")

world= gpd.read_file("//path/to/file/world.shp")

x =  world.to_crs("EPSG:4326")

fix, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8),dpi = 300, subplot_kw={'projection':ccrs.Robinson()})
x.boundary.plot(ax=axes, linewidth=1.5, edgecolor='black')
axes.set_facecolor((0.8,0.8,1,0.5))
DS['Attributable_days_above_18'].plot(ax=axes, vmin =0, vmax = 95, cmap = "viridis", transform = ccrs.PlateCarree())

While Python is able to show me the data, the problem is, it doesn't load the shapefile hence I don't have any country boundaries on it and I want to load the shapefile on it.

Did you mean to specify EPSG:4236 (Hu Tzu Shan 1950), or EPSG:4326 (WGS84)? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360575/difference-between-epsg4236-and-epsg4326
